# How to recieve & store an image file from another server, being passed programatically with paramaters?

Tags: php, image, parameters, store

I am using the API of an image editing website (pixlr.com) for use by members of my site. I open Pixlr.com in an iframe where they can create an image and upon SAVE, pixlr sends the image file by use of parameters.

I want to save these image files (unique for each member) in a folder on my server (or on Amazon's S3 image server), using PHP. How do I receive their parameters ("image") of the image file and store them on my/Amazon's image server?

Comment: Saying "by use of parameters" is vague. Try doing this in your PHP script: `var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_FILES);` and see where the image comes in.

Comment: Or does it pass the image back via JavaScript? If so, does it pass the binary string of the image back, or does it pass a URL to the image? If it is passed back to JavaScript (which is executing on the client-side), then you will need an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to pass the image to your PHP script, which can then save it to a file.

Comment: The image is coming back in a binary string via POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is sent to your PHP script via POST, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
$handle = fopen($imageName, "wb");
fwrite($handle, $_POST["image"]);
fclose($handle);
```

Where `$imageName` is the absolute path and filename of the image where you want to save it (make sure you Apache user has write permissions to that directory). Depending on the picture's encoding you may need to figure out which extension to save it with (ie .jpg, .bmp, .png, etc).

---

**EDIT:**

Looks like they are sending the image via `$_FILES`. Try this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "/home/path/domain.com/upload/". time() .".png");
```

Comment: Thanks much Travesty3. All images will be in png format. How would I add this extension to the file name after it is on my server?

Comment: I'm getting these errors:

`Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in ../test/target.php on line 4` and this one:

`Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in ../test/test.php on line 6`

Comment: @user1322707: You need to set the value of `$imageName` before doing this. You must specify the [absolute path](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm) to the folder and give the file a name, ending with .png. It completely depends on where on your server that you want to save the file. If you are using a Linux server, you might be able to use something like `$imageName = "/var/www/uploadedPictures/". time() .".png";`. You can name the file whatever you want, but you want to give it some sort of unique name to make sure that subsequent uploads don't overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks again Travesty3. We're close! An image file is being saved, but when attempting to open it, it's empty. Also, I get the following error, pointing to `fclose($outputFile);`. Here is the error: `Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/path/domain.com/test.php on line 8` where test.php is the file with the code in it.

Comment: @user1322707: My fault. Copy and paste error in my code. Use `fclose($handle);`.

Comment: I'm using pixlr.com, an image program which is sending the image parameter back as /tmp/p9uinefw without an extension. They do, however, send a separate parameter back with the type of file, which is PNG. Hopefully this helps. Thanks much!

Comment: @user1322707: Can you update your question with the output of `var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: Here's what I'm getting back: `array(3) { ["title"]=> string(14) "filename" ["type"]=> string(3) "png" ["state"]=> string(7) "replace" } array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "filename.png" ["type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpuI1laV" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(15053) } }`

Comment: Here is the complete code I am using:

`var_dump($_POST); 
var_dump($_FILES);

$imageName = "/home/path/domain.com/upload/". time() .".png";

$handle = fopen($imageName, "wb");
fwrite($handle, $_POST["image"]);
fclose($handle);`

Comment: I assume you meant adding the EDIT code to the already existing code. I get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. When using the EDIT code alone, I get the same results

Comment: @user1322707: No, you should just use the EDIT example. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp for an example of what you're trying to do. Specifically, the part where it says **Saving the Uploaded File**.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Travesty3. I think I should be able to figure it out from here.